# how to fix property does not exist on type "Message<MessageType>"

Tags: typescript, protocol-buffers

I have this MessageType extracted from a .proto file:

```
export type MessageType = {

    template_id: number
}
```

Maybe the protobuf library expects to extend with the above Object Type

`class Message<T extends object = object>`

Doing so it results in not finding the type.

```
...
const { template_id }:protobuf.Message<MessageType> = decode(payload)
```

> Property 'template_id' does not exist on type 'Message'.ts(2339)

I tried fixing it by using `unknown` keyword, but this can't be the solution?

```
decode(payload) as unknown as MessageType
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with TypeScript but I think you may be missing a key step in compiling the protobuf source (`.proto`) into language-specific bindings (i.e. TypeScript) before using the results. Check out [`protobufjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobufjs) for examples.